# Request with URL problem specifies Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble collecting some data from the web using the beautifulsoup library and the request library, I make the code and the content I need this inside the div with the class "app", but it does not bring me this content, with any other URL that I put brings me the data that I need, in this url in specific it does not bring me the information, it just shows that it has this div somebody knows what it can be? What is wrong with my code? I'm sending code below.

```
import requests


r = requests.get('http://187.109.199.130:8080/portaltransparencia/servidores/detalhes?matricula=4277', auth=('matricula', 'pass'))

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, would you be able to add the code you are using to extract information? the current code just makes a http request

Comment: Hi, could you also edit your title and translate it to english?

Comment: I've just sent an edit request.

Comment: please post the full code AND the value of `r.text`. Also make sure you can reproduce the problem (http requets can easily fail for quite a lot of reasons and you don't seem to bother testing the response status code).

Comment: This is just an example I made with the same url just to check how the HTML return was from the URL I'm searching for

Comment: his is the answer I have in the body of my HTML page, I need to get the elements that are inside this tag:

<body> <div id = "app"> </ div> <script src = "js / app-f58bdfb6c64af71eaadc.js"> </ script>